# How to handle different versions of source code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, version-control

Initially we didn’t use any source control software.  Now we are using TFS 2010 for version control.  Currently we are facing issue related to how to handle changes with production code and code that is under development.

Assuming we have published a version 1.0 to the web using visual studio 2010 publish with source code x.  Now we continue to work on the source code to implement more features.  Noow the source code has changed to x.something.

During that time we receive bugs reported by users.  Now how to handle such situations since bugs has to be fixed in source code version x.  And we don’t want to use x.something version since it has few unfinished features which we don’t want to publish on production.

At this time what is the recommended practice.

Are there two repositories for different versions of source code?  If yes then how to fix errors when then come –first update current version or the published code, since we don’t want those errors to exist in current development version.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

look into **Branching** - you can find a good guid here:
[TFS Branching Guidance](http://branchingguidance.codeplex.com/)

I think you need/want something like the Branch per Release of Code-Promotion Branches described [here]: [image] or [image]
[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jlbbx.gif)

I like those too, but they are more comples (too complex?):
[image] (taken from [here](http://code-inside.de/blog/2010/04/27/howto-einstieg-in-branching-merging-strategien/) - only in german sorry)

Answer (score 2):

You should put a label on your code when releasing in prod, and then making a branch immediatly.
TFS2010 doesn't support "branching by label" though the UI anymore. See "[Branching by Label in TFS 2010](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitrik/archive/2010/02/18/branching-by-label-in-tfs-2010.aspx)".

[image: Branching by label not there]

If you didn't make a branch dedicated for fixing the bugs in prod right away, you still can use the command line for branching by label. See "[Branch commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d73s8b27.aspx)"

Answer (score 2):

Create a branch for your released version (x) if you haven't already. Fix the bugs in the release branch. Merge the fixes into the development branch (if applicable). http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/ has recommendations on branching and merging.