# Separate Workspaces or Separate Workspace Mappings for different branches of code?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, branch

[From my last question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7349187/how-to-handle-different-versions-of-source-code), I have a little bit understanding of branching code into different branches for development, release, hotfixes, and service pack purposes.  Earlier we had all of our source code into one place (not even folder named Main).  It resided at Team collection $SomeProject along with ProcessTemplates folder.

Created a Main folder on local drive ---
C:\Code\CmdNotify>mdir Main

Added Main to Source Control on the server-----
C:\Code\CmdNotify>tf add Main

Moved code to Main--- 
C:\Code\CmdNotify>tf move *.\Main

Checked in changes to TFS

Now when I create “Main”, “Release”, “ServicePack” branches, how the workspaces work?

- Do we have to create separate workspaces for separate branches?
- Or we have to create separate workspace mappings for separate branches?
- Do we just pull source code from different branches as and when
  needed and then checkin to respective branches? If yes then is this
  done using different mappings or different workspaces?

If anyone can explain with little bit of example or poin to appropriate resource it would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all of your branches aren't too huge, you can just have one workspace with a single mapping for all branches $/ -> C:\Code\CmdNotify.

Then when you Get Latest, it will sync all the branches. It will prompt you if you want to "download the universe". If you don't, everything will still be mapped, but will not be downloaded to your hard drive. You can then download files on demand, as you need them. Just right-click Get Latest on a file or folder in Source Control Explorer.

If your "universe" is several GB or less, I'd just map everything. Having only one workspace for all branches is very convenient if you can afford it (i.e. have the hard drive space for it).

There's also a possibility to "cloak" large folders that you're not using.

Comment: So if there are different mappings for different branches in a single workspace i.e. each branch goes to a different local folder that approach should down respective code for each branch into each folder.    Am I correct with this?  Thanks for answering.

Comment: You're correct. You rarely need more than one workspace per server. Branches go to separate local folders each. Be sure to use Branch to create new branches, Merge to propagate changes from branch to branch and Move to rename/move files/directories within a branch. You can also Move entire branches to a different location.